# My operating system does not start after entering the password

Tags: system

sorry for my English.

My pc no carga despues de que le ingreso mi clave. Despues de ingresar mi clave intenta entrar pero se devuelve al inicio. la pantalla no carga la imagen de  mi escritorio. mi pc es un samsung.

English Translation: My pc is not loading after introducing my password. It gets me back to the initial page. It doesn't load the background image of my desktop. My Pc is a Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when the X Server (The Service that draws stuff to your desktop... *roughly described*) can't start up. You need to get the errors out of the Xorg log file:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
```

... which will then output all Xorg errors. I think that something's wrong with the graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds stupid, but, are you sure of your password? Does it used to work or it is the first time after installing the OS that you try to log in?

Se que suena estupido, pero estás seguro del password? Había funcionado antes o no te funciona justo después de la instalación?